# Are default assignments reliable in HDL?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I always build my design with default assignments because it makes my code fewer lines and I think more readable. However, I learned that the default assignments can be trouble sometimes. If there is not enough space for design, tool (Vivado, ISE) can be removed that part. What I meant is default assignments fill the unwritten else statements. Below piece of code is an example.

I have already checked many times that I saw muxes for these statements in schematic but I never tried it with a design which is fully consumed its resources.

```
t_next <= t_reg;
if(start_i = '1') then
    t_next <= (others => '0');
end if;
```

Is there anyone can say that is there any problem in default assignment? Do I have to write every else or is it enough to write just default assignment for else statement?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know it's perfectly reliable, and never heard about the contrary in 18 years. It's also what I use most of the time, including in FPGA filled above 80 or 90%.
If a tool was to remove the default assignment, it would be a bug of the tool, as it's changing the synthesized logic! VHDL is standardized, it's not as if Xilinx had a choice...
Do you have any source/reference about that statement !?

The only thing I will add is that the code may be a bit harder to read if you have a long process, with the defaults several lines before. But this should not happen often.
And that for initialized **signals** (at definition, for start-up value) it's another story (I don't use that in synthesized logic, ever)

Comment: I have learned from my teacher. She said: "When verification engineers recap the code, they seem that situation as an error because of the above statement." As I said if there is a lack of space into FPGA, IDE could remove those states. However, I never encounter this situation.

Comment: If there is a lack of space, the FPGA build will fail. Compilers should create logic that matches your code behaviour - if it doesnt, then it is a tool bug. It will never remove logic to save space, otherwise it wont function as per the code. If your code is not functioning, I suspect it is a code error, not IDE problem.

Comment: The convention I use to put a comment "// Default" or "-- Default" before the assignments. This indicates to the reader that the signals will be changed further on. (If they are not changed the comment says "Tied off")

Comment: @B. Go I would argue that when done right, such as suggested by Oldfart, that using defaults makes the code more readable than specifying all the values everywhere.   Of course, the OP's code snippet is too small to be worthy of defaults, but the implication is its use in a statemachine which is worthy.

Comment: @JimLewis I agree especially for 1 CLK long pulses. I meant that long horrible processes with tons of signals and even more assignments can get even harder to read if the default is at the top end, far from the "special case". But these long processes should be avoided anyway...

Comment: @B.Go "And that for initialized signals (at definition, for start-up value) it's another story (I don't use that in synthesized logic, ever)."  Exactly.  Though Xilinx and Altera were for a time pushing this in their "reset-less" design guides.  I think this technique can mask very serious issues during simulation.

Comment: Even with Xilinx parts I still use a reset pulse, and that way I'm sure of the exact starting levels. And I can also call them back without fully powering down the device, another reason why resets are useful!